# How to setstate in a loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-state

i am getting error at this.setState({ Url: resp.data.Url }); in GETAPI 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined..
 Please suggest. 
 The GETAPI is basically used to render the data from the API. My use-case is to store all the URLs in state and pass it to DownloadButton component. I need this URL to download the required data.

The hirerachy of code is invokeGetReport which will give all the reports in array. I have looped in and invoked invokeGetReportDetails method. Under invokeGetReportDetails , i am calling invokeImageURL which will contain the URL'of all the reports. I need to store all the URLs in state & passed it to next component

```
class GetAPI extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ID: [],
      Url: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    console.log(this.props.exptype);
    var accesstoken;
    let reports = [];

    axios
      .post(API, qs.stringify(requestBody), config)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        this.setState({ token: result.data.access_token });
        accesstoken = result.data.access_token;
        console.log("access token ins " + accesstoken);
        invokeGetReport(accesstoken);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(error.data);
      });

    function invokeGetReport(accesstoken) {
      console.log("access token is " + accesstoken);
      const config_req = {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + accesstoken,
        },
      };

      axios
        .get(test_report_url, config_req)
        .then((resp) => {
          console.log(resp);
          console.log("data id is " + resp.data.Items.length);

          //  debugger;
          for (let i = 0; i < resp.data.Items.length; i++) {
            let reportName = resp.data.Items[i].Name;
            let reportID = resp.data.Items[i].ID;
            console.log("id is : " + reportID + "Report Name : " + reportName);
            invokeGetReportDetails(accesstoken, reportID);
            reports.push(reportID);
          }
          //  invokeGetReportDetails(accesstoken, reports);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          console.log(error.data);
        });
    }

    function invokeGetReportDetails(accesstoken, reportID) {
      console.log("reportID in detail API is " + reportID);
      const config_req = {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + accesstoken,
        },
      };

      axios
        .get(report_details + reportID, config_req)
        .then((resp) => {
          console.log(resp);
          console.log(
            "report data id is " + resp.data.ExpenseEntriesList.length
          );
          for (let i = 0; i < resp.data.ExpenseEntriesList.length; i++) {
            let expenseEntryId = resp.data.ExpenseEntriesList[i].ReportEntryID;
            let ExpenseTypeName =
              resp.data.ExpenseEntriesList[i].ExpenseTypeName;
            console.log(
              "id is : " +
                expenseEntryId +
                " ExpenseTypeName : " +
                ExpenseTypeName
            );
            invokeImageURL(accesstoken, expenseEntryId);
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          console.log(error.data);
        });
    }

    function invokeImageURL(accesstoken, expenseEntryId) {
      console.log("expenseEntryId in detail API is " + expenseEntryId);

      const config_req = {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + accesstoken,
        },
      };

      axios
        .get(image_url + expenseEntryId, config_req)
        .then((resp) => {
          console.log(resp);
          console.log("URL is " + resp.data.Url);
          this.setState({ Url: resp.data.Url });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          console.log(error.data);
        });
    }

    console.log("repoddrts sdda " + reports[1]);
    console.log("prop value is " + this.props);
    // console.log("report id " + this.state.ID);
  }

  render() {
   return (
      <div>
        <DownloadButton imageUrl={this.Url} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GetAPI;
```

Comment: It's because the "this" you use to change the state refer to the class scope, not for the function scope in the way you declare it.
So for all your different function, try to use an arrow function instead. 
invokeGetReportDetails = () => {}
invokeImageURL = () => {}
invokeGetReport = () => {}

Answer (score 1):

This error is because `this` is not referrring to `GetAPI` component and that's because the way you have nested multiple functions inside `componentDidMount` function.

Write all those functions outside the `componentDidMount` function and use arrow functions.

Not related to the error but you are also not updating the state correctly. You are overwriting it instead of appending the new url to the existing list of urls.

Change

```
this.setState({ Url: resp.data.Url });
```

to

```
this.setState({ Url: [...this.state.Url, resp.data.Url] });
```

Here's the fixed code

```
class GetAPI extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ID: [],
      Url: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.exptype);
    var accesstoken;
    let reports = [];

    axios
      .post(API, qs.stringify(requestBody), config)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        this.setState({ token: result.data.access_token });
        accesstoken = result.data.access_token;
        console.log("access token ins " + accesstoken);
        this.invokeGetReport(accesstoken);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(error.data);
      });

    console.log("repoddrts sdda " + reports[1]);
    console.log("prop value is " + this.props);
    // console.log("report id " + this.state.ID);
  }

  invokeGetReportDetails = (accesstoken, reportID) => {
      console.log("reportID in detail API is " + reportID);
      const config_req = {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + accesstoken,
        },
      };

      axios
        .get(report_details + reportID, config_req)
        .then((resp) => {
          console.log(resp);
          console.log(
            "report data id is " + resp.data.ExpenseEntriesList.length
          );
          for (let i = 0; i < resp.data.ExpenseEntriesList.length; i++) {
            let expenseEntryId = resp.data.ExpenseEntriesList[i].ReportEntryID;
            let ExpenseTypeName =
              resp.data.ExpenseEntriesList[i].ExpenseTypeName;
            console.log(
              "id is : " +
                expenseEntryId +
                " ExpenseTypeName : " +
                ExpenseTypeName
            );
            this.invokeImageURL(accesstoken, expenseEntryId);
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          console.log(error.data);
        });
  }

  invokeImageURL = (accesstoken, expenseEntryId) => {
      console.log("expenseEntryId in detail API is " + expenseEntryId);

      const config_req = {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + accesstoken,
        },
      };

      axios
        .get(image_url + expenseEntryId, config_req)
        .then((resp) => {
          console.log(resp);
          console.log("URL is " + resp.data.Url);
          this.setState({ Url: [...this.state.Url, resp.data.Url] });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          console.log(error.data);
        });
  }

  invokeGetReport = (accesstoken) => {
      console.log("access token is " + accesstoken);
      const config_req = {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + accesstoken,
        },
      };

      axios
        .get(test_report_url, config_req)
        .then((resp) => {
            console.log(resp);
            console.log("data id is " + resp.data.Items.length);

            //  debugger;
            for (let i = 0; i < resp.data.Items.length; i++) {
              let reportName = resp.data.Items[i].Name;
              let reportID = resp.data.Items[i].ID;
              console.log("id is : " + reportID + "Report Name : " + reportName);
              this.invokeGetReportDetails(accesstoken, reportID);
              reports.push(reportID);
            }
          //  invokeGetReportDetails(accesstoken, reports);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          console.log(error.data);
        });
  }

  render() {
   return (
      <div>
        <DownloadButton imageUrl={this.Url} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GetAPI;
```

Comment: @yousaf- the set state is not working.                                                                                        this.setState({ Url: [...this.state.Url, resp.data.Url] });

Comment: what do you mean not working? are you still getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined.`

Comment: i do not see error in console but the state is coming blank

Comment: then your error is fixed. There must be some other problem in your code..

Comment: Thank you, but i am still stuck with this issue of passing the url to next component

Comment: you can create another question, answer to this question ha been given and it has solved the error mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of your functions there is no 'this'.
Move your methods invokeGetReport, invokeGetReportDetails and invokeImageURL to class GetAPI and call them through 'this'.

```
class GetAPI extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        ...
          this.invokeGetReport(accesstoken);
        ...
    }

    invokeGetReportDetails = (accesstoken, reportID) => {
        ...
          this.invokeImageURL(accesstoken, expenseEntryId);
        ...
    };

    invokeImageURL = (accesstoken, expenseEntryId) => {
        ...
         this.setState({ Url: resp.data.Url });
        ...
    };

    invokeGetReport = (accesstoken) => {
        ...
         this.invokeGetReportDetails(accesstoken, reportID);
        ...
    };

    render() {
        ...
    }
}

export default GetAPI;
```

Or use lambda-functions:

```
const invokeGetReportDetails = (accesstoken, reportID) => {...}
const invokeImageURL = (accesstoken, expenseEntryId) => {...}
```

etc

Or call them through fn.call(this)

Comment: Not able to understand, Can you please format the above code and help me out?

Comment: Formatted. Read about javascript closures and 'this'.

[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
and
[closures](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-closure-b2f0d2152b36)